# VS Code does not insert final new line even if "files.insertFinalNewline" is set to true

Tags: visual-studio-code

Strange thing happened out of nothing today. VS Code started to remove final new lines from files, even if

```
"files.insertFinalNewline": true
```

is set.

I tried to manually add final new line but VS Code deletes it on saving. I also tried to remove the line above and change the default setting again. Exit VS Code and opening it again also doesn't help. The editor seems to ignore user settings and defaults to false. Other custom settings don't seem to be affected.

I haven't done any upgrades, haven't changed anything. It happened from one day to the other.

It's very annoying because the linter complains, I can't make pull requests etc. Final new line is a must.

Version: 1.15.1.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I just checked and it works on my machine. Do you have any other settings that might be conflicting?

Comment: I don't think so. It worked perfectly until last night and this strange behaviour started this morning. I temporarily switched to Atom to be able to work as usual but it would be great if this issue was solved.

Comment: I do have the very same issue. I also disabled all my plugins, and it still does not work. (actually, all "files.trim*" settings are fully defunct). My config is [here](https://gist.github.com/flypenguin/f1be771fab84ad55726bbdec24b3b0ae). Anyone any more ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem and was caused by EditorConfig for VS Code plugin. Try disabling this plugin. If that doesn't work, maybe some other plugin is the culprit.

Comment: For me it was the Plugin "JS-CSS-HTML Formatter" by lonefy. Uninstalled this.